# XNA CustomModelAnimationSample problem

Tags: xna-4.0, models, xna-content-pipeline

I downloaded the official tutorial from:[CustomModelAnimationSample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/custom_model_rigid_and_skinned)
It works fine but when I try to replicate it in my project, it fails to load the `Tag` property in my model.

Is found that the probelm is in the line:

```
skinnedModel = Content.Load<Model>("DudeWalk");
```

This line loads the model from the DudeWalk.fbx file and with the custom `SkinnedModelProcessor`. It loads the animations data in the model. After the line the `Tag` property is full. I stepped into the method and it went to the custom `ModelData` class.

I copied everything from the projects `CustomModelAnimationWindows` and `CustomModelAnimationPipeline` to my solution and set all the references. I tried the same line of code and couldn't step in the method. It called the default method or model constructor and after the line the model's `Tag` propetry was `null`.

I have to load the model through my custom `SkinnedModelProcessor` class, but how I tell the game to use this class? In the tutroail [CustomModelClass](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/custom_model_class) the line is changed to:

```
model = Content.Load<CustomModel>("tank");
```

So I assumed that I have to set the generic type to a custom model class, but the first example works without it.

If anyone has some useful advice or some other helpful link, I'll be happy to try it.

**EDIT :**

I tried this tutorial [Creating a Custom Importer and Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447754.aspx) but it didn't work either.

I understand now that the binding of the custom pipeline processor is done at build-time and not a run-time. But my custom processor never gets bound nor called.

Comment: Are your changing the Content Processor of your model in the content project?

Comment: @r2d2rigo: are you saying that this is a problem with the model and not with the application? How do I set up the model for my processor to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do custom processing, you also have to set the importer/processor for the model in question. Go to the Content, click the model and select the desired importer/processor from the properties window.